# Uniqueness of a 2D BVP Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider the following 2D boundary-value problem:
$$
\nabla \cdot [D \nabla u]=0; \space\space\space\space\space\space\space 0 \leq x \leq 2; 0\leq y\leq1\\
u(x=0)=1\\
u(x=2)=0
$$
where $D=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}$;

The boundary conditions are only specified on the left and right boundaries of the domain. There is no condition specified on the top and bottom boundaries.

A solution for this problem is: $u(x,y)=(-3/14)(x+x^3/3)+1$

My question is: Does this boundary-value problem have a unique solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since your boundary is rectangular in shape and your PDE's form allows separation, the solution $u(x,y)$ is separable in the Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$, as can be shown by expanding the $\nabla$ operator explicitly and then taking $u(x,y)\equiv f_{x}(x)f_{y}(y)$. This reduces your PDE to two independent ODEs of the form
$$ (1+x^{2})f_{x}''-2xf_{x}'- k(1+x^{2})f_{x}=0, $$
$$ (1+x^{2})f_{y}''-2xf_{y}'+ k(1+x^{2})f_{y}=0, $$
which are fundamentally the equation
$$ (1+x^{2})y''-2xy'\pm k(1+x^{2})y=0, $$
where $y=y(x)$ is any of the functions $f_{x}$ or $f_{y}$ and $\pm k$ is a constant, with one sign given for the $f_{x}$ case and the other for $f_{y}$ case.

Solving each of these second-order linear ODEs separately will result in two independent integration constants for each equation (i.e. a pair of constants in relation to the $x$ dependence, and another pair in relation to the $y$ dependence). But since the boundary conditions given in your problem statement only fix the constants in the $x$ equation, giving a unique solution in terms of $x$ dependence, the other two constants for the $y$ equation are left unfixed by the boundary conditions given in the problem statement. Therefore, I think it is not a unique solution, since two constants may still be chosen arbitrarily for the $y$ variations of the solution.